# Random Numbers in a Domain with unknown function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, random

I want to create an array of random floating-point numbers in MATLAB that are inside `D`
where the boundary `D` is between

1. `( (0.6+0.1*cos(3t))*cos(t) , (0.6+0.1*cos(3t))*sin(t) ) t \in [0, pi]`
2. `(x,y) where y=0`

How can I create this array in MATLAB?

Something like this picture; red points are on the boundary `D`:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not an optimal solution,
code not tested,
first, create n random coordinates :

```
rc=rand(n,2);
```

then do some repositioning to adjust random number in a square area that closely enough surrounds your closed curve:

```
rc(:,1)=rc(:,1).*1.4-0.7;
rc(:,2)=rc(:,2).*0.7;
```

now you need to throw out positions that are not in your desired area, to check this first create a polygon of your area and then use inpolygon function:

```
t=(0:0.1:pi)';
x=(0.6+0.1*cos(3t)).*cos(t);
y=(0.6+0.1*cos(3t)).*sin(t);

in = inpolygon(rc(:,1),rc(:,2),x,y);
rc(~in,:)=[]; %removing points which are outside of polygon from rc
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I checked the code. Only rc(~in, :)=[]; must be used.

Comment: Excuse me, could you please let me know how do you understand that I must use the following lines?

rc(:,1)=rc(:,1).*1.4-0.7;

rc(:,2)=rc(:,2).*0.7;

Comment: @FAmn it was an example based on your picture , its to adjust random distribution in a square near your area of interest

Comment: It's interesting. Thanks a lot.